# Android Studio: Se me reinicia el Fragmet (Home) al cambiar a otro Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

Soy nuevo en Android Studio, y he hecho un Navigation Drawer. El caso es que he puesto un botón en el Fragment Home que cambia de color y otras cosas. El caso, es que al cambiarme al fragment "Gallery", se me reinicia el Primer Fragment, volviendo al color Inicial (es decir, como si no lo hubiera pulsado). ¿ Cómo hago para que no se me reinicie el primer Fragment y se me mantenga la actividad al moverme en el Navegation Drawer? Muchas gracias

*EDICIÓN -->* Antes que nada, gracias por dedicar tiempo a responder mi pregunta. Y no se si necesitaréis tambien el xml, pero imagino que con esto es suficiente. El Fragment "Home" se me reinicia al volver de "Gallery" a "Home". En el Fragment "Gallery" casi no hay codigo, solo el generado al crear la App con el Navigation Drawer por defecto, por tanto no lo pondré. Muchas Gracias

Código del HomeFragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
    homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            textView.setText(s);

            //Ids
            ivUcar = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ivUcar);
            ivUcarDos = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.ivUcarDos);

            //Ocultar Imagen 2 -- Estetico Caso 1
            ivUcarDos.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            if(pulsado == false) {
                // Cuando presionemos el boton autobus
                ivUcar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (ivUcar.isPressed()) {
                            metContinua();
                            pulsado = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return root;
}

private void estetico () {
    if (!oscuro && continua){
        ivUcarDos.bringToFront();
        ivUcarDos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivUcar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else {
        //NO Oscuro y NO Continua
        ivUcar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ivUcarDos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void metContinua(){
     //Otro método largo, pero que no creo que tenga que ver con el problema
    continua = true;
    //Estetico
    estetico();
}
```

}

Código del Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

}

Comment: Muestra codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: En este sitio acostumbra agregar lo que estas realizando para que sea más fácil ayudarte,saludos.

Comment: ¿Cuándo se te reinicia el fragment Home? ¿Al volver de Gallery a Home? Y como te han indicado, muestra código para poder ayudarte :)